# check for IP address and download the data

Tags: c#

I have two devices having  separate  IP addresses and want to check if any one is connected and if connected  download the database from the device and any given time only one device is connected.My query works fine for one device how to check which one is connected. I have updated my code but not sure how is it gone  work.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// 1)first download database to local system.
{       
    this.Process1();
} 

public void Process1()
{
    string _ftpURL = @"131.000.00.0";  // fake Host URL or address of the SFTP server 
    /* how to check for another IP adddress if exists */

    string _UserName = "root"; //fake User Name of the SFTP server
    string _Password = "3term"; // fake Password of the SFTP server
    int _Port = 2222; //Port No of the SFTP server (if any)
    string _ftpDirectory = "/home/root/systools/WM/WebMobility.db"; //The directory in SFTP server where the files will be uploaded
    string LocalDirectory = "F:\\Explor\\final test"; //Local directory from where the files will be uploaded
    try
    {        
        Sftp Connection = new Sftp(_ftpURL, _UserName, _Password);
        Connection.Connect(_Port);
        Connection.Get(_ftpDirectory, LocalDirectory);
        Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is SshConnectionException || ex is SocketException)
        {
            _ifwInstance.Error(string.Format("Ignoring {0} during listing directory", ex.Message));
        }
        else
        {
            string _ftpURL = @"131.111.11.11";  // fake Host URL or address of the SFTP server 
            /* how to check for another IP adddress if exists */

            string _UserName = "root"; //fake User Name of the SFTP server
            string _Password = "3term"; // fake Password of the SFTP server
            int _Port = 2222; //Port No of the SFTP server (if any)
            string _ftpDirectory = "/home/root/systools/WM/WebMobility.db"; //The directory in SFTP server where the files will be uploaded
            string LocalDirectory = "F:\\Explor\\final test"; //Local directory from where the files will be uploaded
            throw new Exception("Login to SFT FAILED", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

updated Code:

```
string[] _ftpURL = { @"100.100.0.0", @"101.0.0.0" };  //Array of address to SFTP servers
string _UserName = "root"; //fake User Name of the SFTP server
string _Password = "310rp3"; // fake Password of the SFTP server
int _Port = 2222; //Port No of the SFTP server (if any)
string _ftpDirectory = "/home/root/systools/WM/WebMobility.db"; //The directory in SFTP server where the files will be uploaded
string LocalDirectory = "F:\\Explor\\final test"; //Local directory from where the files will be uploaded
bool online = false;
foreach(string furl in _ftpURL)
{
     Sftp Connection = new Sftp(furl, _UserName, _Password);
     try
     {
          Connection.Connect(_Port);
          online = true;
     }
     catch
     {
          online = false;
     }
     if(online == true)
     {
          Connection.Get(_ftpDirectory, LocalDirectory);
          Connection.Close();
          break;
     }
```

}

Comment: Any chance you can rephrase that as I'm struggling to work out what it is you're asking.

Comment: As far as I understand the `Connection.Connect` method should raise an exception if SFTP-host is not accessible. You may catch this exception and try another IP.

Comment: If you are trying to see if a server exists try using System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

Comment: If I have another IP address how to check which one is connected.

Comment: One of possible solution is to call Connection.Connect for list of IPs(devices) until connection is successul and then call  Connection.Get and close

Comment: how to catch an ssh exception#

Comment: I have updated my above code

Answer (score 0):

Add these two methods to some class and call public `DownloadSftpFile` from your desktop code.

```
// returns true if the file had downloaded
public static bool DownloadSftpFile(string[] hosts, int port, string username, string password, string remotePathAndFile, string localPath)
{
    foreach (var host in hosts)
    {
        try
        {
            DownloadSftpFile(host, port, username, password, remotePathAndFile, localPath);
            return true;
        }
        catch(SshConnectionException exception)
        {
            // log
        }
        catch(SocketExcpetion exception)
        {
            // log
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static void DownloadSftpFile(string host, int port, string username, string password, string remotePathAndFile, string localPath)
{
    using (var sftp = new Sftp(host, username, password))
    {
        sftp.Connect(port);
        sftp.Get(remotePathAndFile, localPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark  I wanted to let you know this is what I have done. If possible can you suggest this is correct way  as I know my IP adddress and I may be missing something. Updated Code>.

Comment: As far as I see, your code is correct. For better maintain you could implement downloading in different class/module.